# LinqToSQL: Exclude data from another table, but based on a combination of fields

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a result set of users in a particular position.

Now if I want to exclude users from another list that contains a list of users, this will work:

```
var toExclude = dc.Users.Where(p => p.SomeProperty == true);
positionUsers = positionUsers.Where(p => !toExclude.Select(x => x.UserID).Contains(p.UserID));
```

But now my exclusion list contains **a pair** of users + positions. How do I exclude them now?
If I simply do an && it will exlude all users and all positions in the exclusion list, and not the combination. In other words in needs to do an outer join on 2 fields.

```
var toExclude = dc.UserPositions.Where(p => p.SomeProperty == true).Select(p => new { p.User, p.Position});
positionUsers = positionUsers
                   .Where(p => !toExclude
                                .Select(x => x.UserID + Position)
                                .Contains(p.UserID + Position)); //Obviously this is wrong, but will hopefully explain the requirement.
```

Comment: What is `positionUsers`?

Comment: It can be a SQL table of Users that are linked to different Positions in an Organisation. A user can be linked to many positions and a position can have many users.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var toExclude = dc.UserPositions
                       .Where(p => p.SomeProperty == true)
                       .Select(p => new { p.User, p.Position});
positionUsers = positionUsers
                   .Where(p => !toExclude
                                .Select(x => new { x.UserID, Position })
                                .Contains(new { p.UserID, Position }));
```